# designer file of webpart

Tags: web-part

We use visual studio 2012,sharepoint 2013 and visual source safe 6.0.
We work on code in connected mode on VSS.I had done some changes in a certain code and had checked in into VSS.
The designer file of the webpart that i had worked upon got deleted by one of my colleague.
He recovered the file through VSS.
But now i see the changes done in the .cs file is missing.
I checked the history of the file in VSS and the only thing that i found that designer file was deleted and recovered.

I just wanted to know the missing code is because of the deleted designer file or something else?